# How to keep format (mm/dd/yyyy) in Python when importing dates from Excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a column in an Excel file that is filled with dates, with the `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

I import the column into a list in Python using this code:

```
first_excel_file = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
item_end_date = first_excel_file['Item End Date'].values.tolist()
```

But I get this:

```
[1478476800000000000, 1476921600000000000, 1488240000000000000, 1488240000000000000, 1488240000000000000, 1488326400000000000, 1489622400000000000, 1489622400000000000, 1489968000000000000, 1494288000000000000, 1454198400000000000, 1454198400000000000, 1490918400000000000, 1490918400000000000, 1490918400000000000, 1491955200000000000, 1491955200000000000, 1446249600000000000, 1509408000000000000, 1509408000000000000, 1509408000000000000, 1364688000000000000, 1391126400000000000, 1398816000000000000, 1422662400000000000, 1418428800000000000, 1419292800000000000, 1422662400000000000, 1422662400000000000, 1422662400000000000, 1423612800000000000, 1426291200000000000, 1438300800000000000]
```

How can I import these dates and keep their original formatting instead of getting these numeric values?

Comment: It would help if you showed the code you're currently using to load the file, and specified what the file format is. (Excel accepts lots of different formats.)

Comment: Note that the date format shown in excel for things like a csv rarely matches the format for the file. Is it an actual excel file format or a different format opened in excel?

Comment: @roganjosh it is an actual excel file that someone creates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these timestamps? 
If so, you can convert them into dates.
This may help:

```
from datetime import datetime
item_end_date = [datetime.fromtimestamp(adt//1000000000).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") 
                 for adt in item_end_date]
```

You will get:

```
['11/06/2016', '10/19/2016', '02/27/2017', '02/27/2017', '02/27/2017', 
 '02/28/2017', '03/15/2017', '03/15/2017', '03/19/2017', '05/08/2017', 
 '01/30/2016', '01/30/2016', '03/30/2017', '03/30/2017', '03/30/2017', 
 '04/11/2017', '04/11/2017', '10/30/2015', '10/30/2017', '10/30/2017', 
 '10/30/2017', '03/30/2013', '01/30/2014', '04/29/2014', '01/30/2015', 
 '12/12/2014', '12/22/2014', '01/30/2015', '01/30/2015', '01/30/2015', 
 '02/10/2015', '03/13/2015', '07/30/2015']
```

Comment: item_end_date = [datetime.fromtimestamp(adt//1000000000).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") for adt in item_end_date]

Comment: Just to lower the O() requirements, do it all at once!

Comment: Thank you ! this helped me !